# Rails server issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's my first time to use ruby on rails I installed rails from this link http://railsinstaller.org/en
I created my first project but I facing troubles when trying to run rails server, first, it requires to run

```
 bundle install
```

After running `bundle install`
I see several issues in the command line

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

So how I can fix these pleas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Gemfile try lowering the version of sqlite you're using.

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.3.13'
```

Looking at https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions/1.3.13-x86-mingw23 , 1.3.13 seems to be the latest supported version with mingw23.